# How to feed speech files into RNN/LSTM for speech recognition?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am working on RNN/LSTMs. I have done a simple project with RNN in which i input text into RNNs. But i don't know how to input speech into RNNs and how to preprocess speeches for recurrent networks. I have read many articles from medium and other sites. But i am not able to use speech in the networks. You can share any project in which speech and RNN/LSTMs or anything that can help me.

Comment: I had some good success looking at mycroft-precise source. Tensorflow has some good tutorials as well. I am searching for FPGA examples myself. Like google aiy kit. When I get time at least.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to convert raw audio signal into spectrogram or some other convenient format that is easier to process using RNN/LSTMS. [This](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/machine-learning-is-fun-part-6-how-to-do-speech-recognition-with-deep-learning-28293c162f7a) medium blog should be helpful. You can look at [this github repo](https://github.com/zzw922cn/Automatic_Speech_Recognition) for implementation.

Comment: I am not understanding that should i feed the features in matrix form or something else ?